# What is the reason for fetch not working even though the response is perfect from Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, fetch

Giving a fetch request from react js element to fetch the list of all company objects,the response in the dev tools is correct and the request is working fine from SpringBoot Side
But still the fetch is not working as its most probably throwing an error

Fetch Code:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8088/companies/', {
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            if (res.ok)
                return res.json()
            throw res
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            setCompanies(data)
        })
```

If I dont use res.ok => it gives error,here it does not give error but when I print data it gives `undefined`

Spring Boot Controller Code:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<?> findAllCompanies(){
    log.info("Inside findAllCompanies of CompanyController");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(companyService.findAllCompanies());
}
```

Spring Boot Service Implementation Code:

```
@Override
public List<CompanyDTO> findAllCompanies() {
    return companyRepository.findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(company -> companyMapper.map(company,CompanyDTO.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[Network Layer Correct Output of /companies/ API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wka9c.png)

[Error Thrown in fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiiO1.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to use the [`json()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) on the response to read the stream and parse as json. The TL;DR: `return res.json()`

Comment: @Nick Did it same issue ,it is failing in the first then already

Comment: Can you update your code including the `.json()` method?

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: @Nick have also include the image of the error thrown in the first `then` itself

Comment: The response is opaque, meaning you’re probably hitting cors issues. Is your react app running on a port that your backend has specified as an allowed origin?

Comment: @Nick  have enabled cors for every origin in spring boot ,as you can see in the 1st image im also recieving the correct output i.e. the List of company Objects here only 1

Comment: Can you try removing the mode: no-cors option? Pretty sure that will force an opaque response on a cross origin request.

Comment: - that wat already removed